# how to get the data click on the show product using AngularJS asp.net mvc?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to show product after login click on show my product link in my shopping cart demo using AngularJS,i have got the error just only show table header did't show my product data in asp.net mvc..i m tried this below code..

```
$scope.ViewPro = function () {
    debugger;        
    $http({ method: 'POST', url: 'AddToCart/ProList' }).
    success(function (p) {
        debugger;
        console.log(p);
        $scope.Products = p; // Response Data                 
        $location.path('/ViewProduct');
    }).
    error(function (data) {
        alert(data + "Error");
        console.log(data);
    });
};
```

this is my router provider..

```
.when('/ViewProduct', { templateUrl: 'AddToCart/ViewProduct' })
```

this is my mvc method..

```
   public JsonResult ProList()
    {
        var ProductList = db.tblProducts.ToList();
        var details = ProductList.Select(d => new
        {
            d.ProductId,
            d.ProductName,
            d.Price,
            d.Descripation,
            d.SEOURL,
            d.Image,
            d.IsPubliesd,
        }).ToList();
        return Json(details, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

this is my view..

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><b>ProductId</b></td>
                <td align="center"><b>ProductName</b></td>
                <td align="center"><b>Descripation</b></td>
                <td align="center"><b>Price</b></td>
                <td align="center"><b>SEOURL</b></td>
                <td align="center"><b>IsPubliesd</b></td>                    
                <td align="center"><b>AddToCart</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="Product in Products">
                <td>{{Product.ProductId}}</td>
                <td>{{Product.ProductName}}</td>
                <td>{{Product.Descripation}}</td>
                <td>${{Product.Price}}.00</td>
                <td>{{Product.SEOURL}}</td>               
                <td>{{product.ispubliesd}}</td>                                      
            </tr>
        </table>
```

this is my small demo for the shopping cart i have the error i m not getting product after login so please help me any one idea..

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing your products to another view . You should use routeParams for passing data between views .
Here is the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams)

Comment: hello Ghazanfar i have just show prouct list i have no use any product id for the get product list..so please tell me briefly explain this my error above code..plaese help me..routeParams are use with the id..

Comment: hello Ghazanfar any idea above this my error...so please help me